# AngularJS Token Security

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an AngularJS Bearer authentication with token (the backend is .net) and it works fine. So I set the value of the token like this:

```
eG31St7ldCYAzRCBFXK0jznKzvZ7TWHatK29Fm3SNxUxLbRudgaN-AphjsVvN5SVyIUMUrX2TrOe-oYa2JCNThjLf3yJdEXC2BXmp-xDFjyfvv4hldtNSZ1YddjSHMaJZ6wUmLWATcV8ieiga_ENsWvcu7DWJ2pAjWYzFEdAdGUaAdGCUpO_t9loG_l8o65bY0riXyEM8VUSlQ4NBcoPUCohQdII89rfzJ8N--FYp9eLXk2UgtHax3dTyop5gX0J
```

for example, in the Session Store.

The question is how do I prevent the user from copying and pasting the token value from Session Storage (using say chrome dev tools) and the app says "is logged in"?

What do you suggest? I tested putting the value in a factory but when I refresh the page, the token is gone. I'm totally new on AngularJS.

Comment: To store the token on a locale storage or something like that is the correct way. You should check if the token is still valid when it gets readout from the locale storage again.

Comment: Thanks @blacksheep_2011... how i do to check if the token is still valid or not? Im new on this, sorry

Comment: If you use JWT you can do it with various libraries. They are easy to find on the internet. Another solution is to make a rest call, which you send the token and it says if it is valid. Here an blog entry for token auth with angularJs and asp.net maybe it helps: http://www.get-the-solution.net/index-blog-1-14-176-Add-Token-Authorizat.html

Comment: Mmmmm... there is a way to tells the api that delete the token?

Comment: Of cause you can write a method in your REST api to delete the token. But when will you trigger this?

Comment: Mmm... when the users logout for example....or not? When you suggest to do this? Sorry! im new!! im sloooow to learn this! :O

Comment: The token it self should have a expire date, so it is not valid all time. For the case the user didn't logout himself. And yes you should remove the token when the user logs out. Create a logout method in your REST-API which deletes the token. In angularJs have a logout button which calls a function that then make a request to your logout method of your REST-API

Comment: Ok im now to implement this method... one last question... this duration of the token tha i set on my backend (for example 1 day) means that will expire 1 day with or without use of the calls or means that will expires 1 day if the token is no more used?

Comment: It means the token is valid then for 1 day from the creation point. But you have not to implement JWT by your self there are finished libraries for this. e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn205065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 can you take a minute and see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552448/web-api-2-owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-logout)? They said that the bearer resides on the client side and if i delete from the Session Storage its done... but the problem is if anything is able to intercept this Bearer before the sessions close... Apparently there's not an answer for that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102179/discussion-between-blacksheep-2011-and-ali-briceno).