# owin token base authentication signout not working in asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I am trying to make Logout url. If user hit Logout url by pass header token then this token must expire.

I did the code for the same, But it is not working. I didn't found solution in any blog.
My code given below,

**First Way (Not Working)**

```
[Route("Logout")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Logout()
{
    authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie,
                          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);

    authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authentication.SignOut();

}
```

**Second Way (Not Working)**

```
[Route("LogOut")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage LogOut()
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);

AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5)
});
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);

var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
var ClientId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Constants.USERID).Value;
var USERNAME = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Constants.USERNAME).Value;
var PASSWORD = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Constants.USER_PASSWORD).Value;

var oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();
oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-5).Ticks);

var context = new OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(), null, ClientId, USERNAME, PASSWORD, null);
context.Validated(ticket);

}
```

But token doesn't expire in both way.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not just a case of the client app forgetting the bearer token?

Comment: User can generate new token by login if he forgot the token. But I am actually looking for when user click on logout button at that time issued token should expire.

Comment: Some thoughts here in this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552448/web-api-2-owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-logout

Comment: I have also go through this but How can I add/append unique key in token?