# How to Logout of Owin Providers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/using-owin-external-login) yet it does not tell you how to logout. I tried to do

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut()

          Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

You can get the sample code here: https://github.com/AndersAbel/SocialLoginWithoutIdentity

Just need to add one more action

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
 {
       Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```

This method plus any one of the 3 lines of I posted above

My result right now is, I login, I go to secure page and can see it, I then proceed to my signout and then after signout try to go back to the secure page and I am allowed back to that secure page.

So it actually did not really sign me out.

Comment: Does it not log you out?

Comment: No. I can access my secure pages without logging in. It seems to recreate the cookie with all the claims in it. It's like it's on auto login forever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24611815/2850543

Comment: you have to share more of your implementation. Hard to even imagine using the middleware to login yet the logout not working. The Out-of-Box functionality is consistent.

Comment: My code is the tutorials code + signout action method what has just that 2s line in it, one of the 3 lines I have in my OP and redirect to home page. You can get the code here and just need to add one of those lines I posted and see https://github.com/AndersAbel/SocialLoginWithoutIdentity

Comment: @MillieSmith - How do you delete the access token? If there is no signout why is there a signout method part of the OwinContext?

Comment: when you say "go back" to a secure page, do you mean actually clicking the back button in browser?

Comment: @Juventus18 - No I mean, your kicked back to my home page on logout and you go to your url bar and type in the url of the secure page.

Comment: looked at your Account Controller in GitHub, and **there is no logoff method**. Please Elaborate...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - It's not my code, that's my whole problem. I am following a tutorial that does not tell you how to LogOff. I am trying to add that functionality by building on that example but have unable to figure out how to logoff.

Comment: Odd. Your logout method should work. I'd recommend starting over with an out-of-box solution. They always work well and your example is both old and incomplete. Whether you want cookie or token auth, this is a bad example to work with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in the tutorial, the middleWare used use the default authentication type but don't override it.

By using only externalCookie as parameter for Owin you are clearing the cookie for Asp, **but not the one used to store the Google provider**,

to do so, you will have to get the array of all current cookies.
It can be done the easy way like this:

```
Request.GetOwinContext()
       .Authentication
       .SignOut(HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                           .Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes()
                           .Select(o => o.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
```

This is where it is said on the [Tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/using-owin-external-login):

> The call to UseGoogleAuthentication should be quite obvious why it’s needed.
>
> But the first one toSetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType is not as
> obvious.
> login middleware normally relies on the external cookie middleware
> registered before the social login middleware.
> external cookie middleware, it sets itself as the default signin type.
> That’s how the social login middleware knows that it should use the
> external cookie. **In this setup there is no external cookie, so we have
> to manually set the main cookie middleware as the default signin type.**
> The cookie middleware will only issue a cookie if the
> AuthenticationType matches the one in the identity created by the
> social login middleware.Looking at the owin external authentication pipeline a socialIn the setup of the

Comment: This seems to work. I am a bit confused what does clearing only the cookie for ASP do then? What do you mean 100% by "default authentication type but don't override it". I thought External Cookie actually referred to cookies made by something like Google. Not to The Asp cookie.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language so it may not mean what I want it to mean, but, it's explained in the link on this paragraphe:

Comment: arf Internet issue, well, I updated my answer to show where I got the solution in the Tutorial.

Comment: it didn't worked in my case. i placed it in login action

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the cache control headers.

```
public ActionResult SignOut() {
    var authenticationTypes = new string[] {
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,  
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie 
    };
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(authenticationTypes);
    // HACK: Prevent user from being able to go back to a logged in page once logged out
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    // now redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");    
}

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
    get {
        return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

There is no stopping the user clicking the back button on the browser, unless you try JavaScript, which can be disabled. The user can go back a page and view what was on the previous page, but if they try to click any protected links or refresh the page, they will be redirected to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Authorize] attribute on classes which need authorization:

```
 [Authorize]
public class MeController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
        var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        return identity.Claims.Select(c => new
        {
            Type = c.Type,
            Value = c.Value
        });
    }
}
```

source: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Comment: I have authorize tags on my stuff right now that is not the problem. The problem is I followed the tutorial and added a signout method(which has 2 lines of code in it, one of the 3 in my OP and redirect to home page). When I click signout and then go back to a secure page, I still can access that secured page even though I should be actually logged out. It never actually logs me out.