How do I get the Owin AuthenticationType set by UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication?
I can read the AuthenticationType I set when I called UseCookieAuthentication by enumerating User.Identities, but it does not include the AuthenticationType that I set with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication.  I need both to successfully log out with SignOut.  How do I get the AuthenticationType I had set in UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication?
New Info:
I found some code that gives me all of the AuthenticationTypes configured in my application (the 2 openid AuthenticationTypes and Cookies), but when I call SignOut on all 3 I get an error.  If I force it to only call with the 1 correct openid AuthenticationType and Cookies, I do not get an error.  How do I get just the correct 2 AuthenticationTypes without the extra one?
var owinContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.GetOwinContext();
                if (owinContext != null)
                {
var authenticationTypes = owinContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(i => i.AuthenticationType).ToArray();
                    owinContext.Authentication.SignOut(authenticationTypes);
                    
                }

There is a similar issue documented in this other discussion, but it does not acknowledge the error when calling SignOut of all 3 AuthenticationTypes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38567468/4194514
