# LogOut with WebAPI from Azure

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, webapi

I'm using OAuth2 to log in with my .NET WebAPI to Azure DevOps, but I don't know how to log out despite deleting the token. Is there any log out website of Microsoft or somethin like that, that I could use?

Comment: Your question is unclear,  are you looking for access token revokation ? See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadministration/token%20revocations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: In the token-based authentication process in OAuth2.0, resources are provided through validation within the token. In other words, if you delete the token, the resource cannot be used. This allows you to logout at the front level without requesting to the backend server, and eventually logout on the web browser is a process of deleting the token, and that's enough.

Comment: Yes, I know and at that time I already tried that but when reloading the page it automatically logged in the user so there was no possibility of logging in with another user besides deleting the cookies. And thats not really the point of logging out of a website. That's why I asked. I found the solution, it was redirecting to https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signout. Now when logging out the user can restart the page and log in with another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was redirecting the user to

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signout
```

for logging out. It logs out the user and when restarting the web app the user can choose a different account.

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser does not cache the credentials or the access token, logging out is simply a matter of "forgetting" the token, by removing it from session storage:

```
self.logout = function () {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey)
}
```

This is mentioned in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api#log-out), please refer to it.

Comment: that's strange, my browser does cache the credentials
I'm already deleting the token, but it's not enough

Comment: @Nok Since OAuth is not an authentication protocol, there is no notion of signout. Delete the access token on the client - that's all you can do. If you want to invalidate the token on the server side, add a unique id to it and keep track in your service - you would need to manually build something like that. Here is a reference [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24611815/11508192).